# Trying to extract Photoshop layer co-ordinates and dimensions

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

**Example Photoshop file:**

```
[Layer 1]
[Group 1]
   [Layer 2]
   [Layer 3]
[Layer 4 (Hidden)]
[Layer 5]
```

**Desired Output** (*colon separated text file*):

```
Layer 1:x:y:w:h
Group 1:Layer 2:x:y:w:h
Group 1:Layer 3:x:y:w:h
Layer 5:x:y:w:h
```

As you can see, I am trying to write the names of each layer with its co-ordinates and dimensions to a colon separated text file. Ignoring any hidden layers and appending the group name to any layers within groups.
I can get the co-ordinates and dimensions for each layer with this script:

```
// Enables double-click launching from the Mac Finder or Windows Explorer
#target photoshop

// Bring application forward
app.bringToFront();

// Set active Document variable and decode name for output
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var docName = decodeURI(activeDocument.name);

// Define pixels as unit of measurement
var defaultRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

// Define variable for the number of layers in the active document
var layerNum = app.activeDocument.artLayers.length;

// Define variable for the active layer in the active document
var layerRef = app.activeDocument.activeLayer;

// Define varibles for x and y of layers
var x = layerRef.bounds[0].value;
var y = layerRef.bounds[1].value;
var w = layerRef.bounds[2].value;
var h = layerRef.bounds[3].value;
var coords = "";

// Loop to iterate through all layers
function recurseLayers(currLayers) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < currLayers.layers.length; i++ ) {
    layerRef = currLayers.layers[i];
    if (!layerRef.visibility) {
        continue;
    }       
    x = layerRef.bounds[0].value;
    y = layerRef.bounds[1].value;
    w = layerRef.bounds[2].value - x;
    h = layerRef.bounds[3].value - y;
    coords += layerRef.name + ":" + x + ":" + y + ":" + w + ":" + h + "\n";

    //test if it's a layer set
    if ( isLayerSet(currLayers.layers[i]) ) {
      recurseLayers(currLayers.layers[i]);
    }
  }
}

//a test for a layer set
function isLayerSet(layer) {
  try {
    if ( layer.layers.length > 0 ) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}

// Ask the user for the folder to export to
var FPath = Folder.selectDialog("Save exported coordinates to");

// Detect line feed type
if ( $.os.search(/windows/i) !== -1 ) {
  fileLineFeed = "Windows";
}
else {
  fileLineFeed = "Macintosh";
}

// Export to txt file
function writeFile(info) {
  try {
    var f = new File(FPath + "/" + docName + ".txt");
    f.remove();
    f.open('a');
    f.lineFeed = fileLineFeed;
    f.write(info);
    f.close();
  }
  catch(e){}
}

// Run the functions
recurseLayers(docRef);
preferences.rulerUnits = defaultRulerUnits; // Set preferences back to user 's defaults
writeFile(coords);

// Show results
if ( FPath == null ) {
  alert("Export aborted", "Canceled");
}
else {
  alert("Exported " + layerNum + " layer's coordinates to " + FPath + "/" + docName + ".txt " + "using " + fileLineFeed + " line feeds.", "Success!");
}
```

*Above script originally provided on this site by Chris DeLuca with a small modification by me to provide the dimensions.*
However, that lists all layers whether or not they are hidden and doesn't care about groups (Layer Sets - right?)

In an attempt to ignore hidden layers I changed the recursive function to this:

```
// Loop to iterate through all layers
function recurseLayers(currLayers) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < currLayers.layers.length; i++ ) {
    layerRef = currLayers.layers[i];
    if (!layerRef.visibility) {
        continue;
    }       
    x = layerRef.bounds[0].value;
    y = layerRef.bounds[1].value;
    w = layerRef.bounds[2].value - x;
    h = layerRef.bounds[3].value - y;
    coords += layerRef.name + "," + x + "," + y + "," + w + "," + h + "\n";

    //test if it's a layer set
    if ( isLayerSet(currLayers.layers[i]) ) {
      recurseLayers(currLayers.layers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Thinking that it would ignore any hidden layers. Unfortunately that produces a zero byte file.

So, ignoring that issue for now and trying the grouping problem.
I don't want a group to be listed but I do want the groups name to be appended to the beginning of any layers that are within the group.  I tried this:

```
    // Loop to iterate through all layers
function recurseLayers(currLayers) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < currLayers.layers.length; i++ ) {
    layerRef = currLayers.layers[i];
    x = layerRef.bounds[0].value;
    y = layerRef.bounds[1].value;
    w = layerRef.bounds[2].value - x;
    h = layerRef.bounds[3].value - y;
    coords += group + ":" + layerRef.name + ":" + x + :," + y + ":" + w + ":" + h + "\n";
    group = "";

    //test if it's a layer set
    if ( isLayerSet(currLayers.layers[i]) ) {
        group = currLayers.layers[i]
        recurseLayers(currLayers.layers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

But that only appends the group name to the first layer within it. Understandable really but I can't figure out how to get each layers parent group.

Any help with one or both of those issues would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: According to documentation, `visible` is a property you want to use, not `visibility`

Comment: You're right! I've changed that and now that part of it works. Thank you.  I'd still appreciate help with the grouping though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been tinkering for a couple of hours and managed to answer my own question.
It's a bit hacky and I'm sure there is a more elegant solution but it works!

Here it is if anyone else needs it:

```
#target photoshop

// Bring application forward
app.bringToFront();

// Set active Document variable and decode name for output
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var docName = decodeURI(activeDocument.name);

// Define pixels as unit of measurement
var defaultRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

// Define variable for the number of layers in the active document
var layerNum = app.activeDocument.artLayers.length;

// Define variable for the active layer in the active document
var layerRef = app.activeDocument.activeLayer;

// Define varibles for x and y of layers
var x = layerRef.bounds[0].value;
var y = layerRef.bounds[1].value;
var w = layerRef.bounds[2].value;
var h = layerRef.bounds[3].value;
var coords = "";
var group = "";
var layersInGroup = 0;
var thisGroupsLayer = 0;
var inGroup = false;

// Loop to iterate through all layers
function recurseLayers(currLayers) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < currLayers.layers.length; i++ ) {
    layerRef = currLayers.layers[i];
    if (!layerRef.visible) {
        continue;
    }

    if (isLayerSet(currLayers.layers[i]) == 0){
        x = layerRef.bounds[0].value;
        y = layerRef.bounds[1].value;
        w = layerRef.bounds[2].value - x;
        h = layerRef.bounds[3].value - y;
        coords += group + layerRef.name + ":" + x + ":" + y + ":" + w + ":" + h + "\n";
    }

    if (inGroup && thisGroupsLayer == layersInGroup){
        inGroup = false;
        group = "";
        thisGroupsLayer = 0;
    }

    if (inGroup && thisGroupsLayer != layersInGroup){
        thisGroupsLayer++;  
    }

    if (!inGroup){
        layersInGroup = isLayerSet(currLayers.layers[i]);
        if ( layersInGroup ) {
            var groupname = currLayers.layers[i].toString();
            group = groupname.substring(0, groupname.length-1);
            group = group.slice(10, group.length)+":";
            inGroup = true;
            thisGroupsLayer++;
            recurseLayers(currLayers.layers[i]);
        }
    }
  }
}

//a test for a layer set
function isLayerSet(layer) {
  try {
    if ( layer.layers.length > 0 ) {
      return layer.layers.length;
    }
  }

  catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}

// Ask the user for the folder to export to
var FPath = Folder.selectDialog("Save exported coordinates to");

// Detect line feed type
if ( $.os.search(/windows/i) !== -1 ) {
  fileLineFeed = "Windows";
}
else {
  fileLineFeed = "Macintosh";
}

// Export to txt file
var filename = docName.substring(0, docName.length - 4) + " subimages.txt";
function writeFile(info) {
  try {
    var f = new File(FPath + "/" + filename);
    f.remove();
    f.open('a');
    f.lineFeed = fileLineFeed;
    f.write(info);
    f.close();
  }
  catch(e){}
}

// Run the functions
recurseLayers(docRef);
preferences.rulerUnits = defaultRulerUnits; // Set preferences back to user 's defaults
writeFile(coords);

// Show results
if ( FPath == null ) {
  alert("Export aborted", "Canceled");
}
else {
  alert("Exported " + layerNum + " layer's coordinates to " + FPath + "/" + filename + " using " + fileLineFeed + " line feeds.", "Success!");
}
```